# Aligning Matrices?

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

How would I align matrixes more correctly?

I tried to use `array` with filling top cells and left one at the bottom, but it doesn't really work. Currently its implemented as

```latex
$
\begin{bmatrix}
400. & 0.   & 0. & 100.\\ 
  0. & 700. & 0. & 0. \\
  0. & 100. & 200. & 300. \\
  0. & 0. & 0. & 200.
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}500.\\  700.\\ 600.\\  200.\\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}500. &  700. & 600. &  200.  \end{bmatrix}
$
```

I am limited to LaTeX implemented in [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to align?  The decimal points?

Comment: MathJax is not LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

This works very conveniently because the largest element in both matrices is of the form 3 digits and a decimal point.  I changed the numbers somewhat to show that each column need not be of this format, only that the largest element of both matrices should be so.  If they were not, a single `\phantom` could rectify the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\stackMath
\fixTABwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\stackunder[6pt]{
  \bracketMatrixstack[c]{
  400. & 0.& 0. &0.\\
  0. & 700. & 0. & 0.\\
  0. & 100. & 2. & 30.\\
  0. & 0. & 0. & 10.
  }
}{
  \bracketMatrixstack{400. & 800. & 200. & 500.}
}
\bracketVectorstack{500.\\700.\\600.\\100.}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, looks like result going to be exactly the same as I have by simply added matrix on a new row

Comment: @Butuzov There will be a significant difference if one of the columns does not follow the form `xxx.`  Then, your approach will not be so pretty.  For example, change the bottom `bmatrix` to `\begin{bmatrix}500. &  700. & 6. &  20.  \end{bmatrix}` and see what it looks like.

Comment: @Butuzov  Furthermore, your stacked matrices will be left-aligned, not center-aligned.

Comment: I see your point and perhaps you right, and I am just fighting with something I can't handle... =(